# how to change background color of ElevatedButton after pressed in flutter but i have three so one should change when selected

Tags: flutter

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LpWw0.png)

I have three buttons when i press one i don't want all of them to change the background color only selected one can, so how can i achieve this?

Comment: can you put your minimal sample code here instead of image ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to below code hope it help for you :

Create `ElevatedButton` **Widget**.

```
ElevatedButton(
        child: Text('Elevated Button'),
        onPressed: () {
          print('Pressed');
        },
        style: ButtonStyle(
          backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith<Color>(
            (Set<MaterialState> states) {
              if (states.contains(MaterialState.pressed))
                return Colors.blue;
              return Colors.green;
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
```