# Using states in MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith<Color>

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-animation

I'm trying to figure out if there is a way to use the states below, somewhere else.

```
TextButton(
onPressed: () {},
style: ButtonStyle(
  backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith<Color>(
    (states) { /*can we use this 'states' on other widget?*/
      if (states.contains(MaterialState.hovered)) {
        return Colors.red;
      }
      return Colors.white;
    },
  ),
),
child: Text(
  "change red color when hover",
    ),
);
```

Is there a way that we can use the states in other places/widgets?

Comment: If you change the color of button when you hover it or pressed it refer my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/68630643/13997210 I have use here **ElevatedButton** , just change the `MaterialState.pressed` or `MaterialState.hover` use of your needs

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking into listening into the current state the property is in, then you may consider using [Stream](https://dart.dev/tutorials/language/streams).

```dart
class HoverState {
  final _state = StreamController<MaterialState>.broadcast();
  Stream<MaterialState> get showState => _state.stream;

  setCondition(MaterialState state) {
    _state.sink.add(state);
  }

  disposeCondition() {
    _state.close();
  }
}
```

...and on your Widget, you can update the Stream with:

```dart
// Initialize class containing Stream broadcast
HoverState hoverState = HoverState();

...

(states) { /*can we use this 'states' on other widget?*/
  if (states.contains(MaterialState.hovered)) {
    return Colors.red;
  }
  return Colors.white;

  // Update state in Stream
  hoverState.setCount(states);
},
```