# Flutter: Change the background color of selected button in ListView.builder

Tags: flutter, dart, listview, button, builder

I have a list of items and default color.

```
List<String> items = ['A', 'B', 'C'];
Color _color = Colors.transparent;
```

From my code, it changes all the background colors of the buttons.

```
ListView.builder(
  itemCount: items.length,
  itemBuilder: (context, index) {

    return ElevatedButton(
      style: ButtonStyle(backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(_color)),
      onPressed: () {
        setState(() {
          _color = Colors.blue;
        });
      },
      child: Text(items[index]),
    );

  },
);
```

So, I want only the selected button to change the background color.

Comment: try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68630643/13997210) if you are pressed button then change the color of button

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try with this

```
List<String> items = ['A', 'B', 'C'];
List<Color> _color = [Colors.transparent,Colors.transparent,Colors.transparent ];

ListView.builder(
        itemCount: items.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return ElevatedButton(
            style: ButtonStyle(
                backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(_color[index])),
            onPressed: () {
              setState(() {
                if (_color[index] == Colors.blue) {
                  _color[index] = Colors.transparent;
                } else {
                  _color[index] = Colors.blue;
                }
              });
            },
            child: Text(items[index]),
          );
        },
      );
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Nice. What if those buttons act like radio buttons? For example, button A is selected, then I tap button B, then I want button B to be the only one with a blue background color.

Comment: Yes, but I forgot to mention the buttons to act like radio.

Comment: Nvm, I found it here [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50060276/flutter-custom-radio-button)